# Sending data from Angular 1.x Factory to Angular 1.x controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-resource

I have a service defined which do the db related queries/updates. I have defined the controller which does the data parsing for the angular elements by getting the objects from the service. I would like to keep each scope different

How can I pass the data from service to controller using ngResource.

Sample Service:

```
app.factory("ioHomeService", ["$rootScope","$resource", function($rootScope,$resource) {
   var svc = {};
   var home = $resource('/home/getAll');
   var dbData= home.get();
   svc.getRooms = function() {
       return dbData;
   };
    return svc;
}]);
```

Sample Controller:

```
app.controller("homeCtrl",["$scope","$mdDialog","ioHomeService",function($scope,$mdDialog,ioHome){
    $scope.dbData = ioHome.getRooms();
    //Here UI specific objects/data is derived from dbData
}]);
```

After the DB is queried and the results are avialble the dbData in service is reflecting the data from DB, but the Controller cannot get that data

Comment: Actually you code has lots of problem. $resource is an asynchronized call. You should get familiar with Promise & $q before going any deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Since the 'ioHome.getRooms();' is being called before the $resource has returned the data you are getting dbData as an empty reference

```
app.factory("ioHomeService", ["$rootScope","$resource", function($rootScope,$resource) {
   var svc = { 
     dbData : {}
   };
   var home = $resource('/home/getAll');
   var svc.dbData.rooms = home.get();
   return svc;
}]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller("homeCtrl",["$scope","$mdDialog","ioHomeService",function($scope,$mdDialog,ioHome){
    $scope.dbData  = ioHome.dbData;

    //You can access the rooms data using $scope.dbData.roooms

    //Here UI specific objects/data is derived from dbData
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to return the service object , like so :

```
app.factory("ioHomeService", ["$rootScope","$resource",   function($rootScope,$resource) {
var svc = {};
var home = $resource('/home/getAll');
var dbData= home.get();
svc.getRooms = function() {
   return dbData;
};
return svc; //here
}]);
```

Currently the `getRooms` method is not visible to your controller.

Comment: Sorry. I did added the return svc in the code. Still recieve the empty object